# How to insert data from list to a column of data grid view

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a data grid view (dataGridViewPorosity) with 2 columns and I want to insert data from a list (Porosity) to one of this columns, but the exception is:
Index was out of range. most be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

here is my code:

```
        var source = new BindingSource
        {
        DataSource = Porosity
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
        {
             dataGridViewPorosity[1,i].Value = source[i];
        }
```

I saw the similar questions but cannot fix the problem

Comment: You should do `dataGridViewPorosity[i,1].Value`

Comment: the 1 is the column index

Comment: Correct .  1 is column index that's why you need to do `[i,1]`. A cell in gridview is located based on row index first and then column index. Did you try the way I suggested?

Comment: No Its wrong, column index first and then row index!

Comment: If it still doesn't work, debug and check the length of souce list and cross reference with the dataGridViewPorosity dimensions, you might have to many items in your source.

Comment: thank you, but it still doesn't work...!

Comment: Can you check how many items are there in `source` array and how many rows are there in the gridview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataGridView control works differently from the other tables you might know (or arrays).
You need to choose the row and cell. The cell is basically the column.

```
dataGridViewPorosity.Rows[rowNumber].Cells[cellNumber].Value = source[i];
```

I assume you want to use the second cell and the row with the `i` value. You can do it just like that:

```
dataGridViewPorosity.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = source[i];
```

Good luck!

***EDIT*:**
Try to create new rows, like so:

```
int rownum = dataGridViewPorosity.Rows.Add();
```

And then use the rownum as the row number you would like to insert your data to.

```
dataGridViewPorosity.Rows[rownum].Cells[1].Value = source[i];
```

Of course, these must be in the for loop.

Comment: Did you create any rows?

Comment: No problem! Goodluck!